# Android Text highlighter

Tags: android, text

Hello All
   Is it possible to highlight the text in android word by word in regular interval of time.if yes, then how to achieve this..
I had already worked for this and got success in highlighting the paragraph line by line instead word by word by using spannable class but the code become more lengthy and i think it may become unmanageable if done word by word.

Any appropriate solution or idea about how to do this in better way.Thank in advance

-Gourav

Comment: Do you want to highlight in html? And where do you highlight the text, in a TextView or WebView or ...?

Comment: thanks dbrettschneider for ur response, I m using textview alongwith  html to set text in textview like-       **textView1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#2a8e94\">MY TEXT</font>"), BufferType.SPANNABLE);**

Comment: I think it is the appropriate way to use the font tag. Just wrap the words you want to highlight with it.

Comment: Thanks again... but the high-lighten text is vary with the time and i m unable to control them properly even with an another thread. Any app or snippet where such kind of functionality (word by word highlighting w.r.t. time) is implemented in android.

Comment: I have to implement that too in some time and I dont find a good example. I think I will implement my own TextView with a setHighlight(String) function. Then I will override the setText() so that it searches for highlightable words first and generates some kind of html string. I can give you an example when I have done this but I will start only in some weeks.